# Is the name of the file mapping object needed on a file backed CreateFileMapping?

Tags: winapi, shared-memory

The MS Windows [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method takes a file handle argument and a file mapping object name argument. All the examples I have found show using the name argument in conjunction with the INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE to create a file mapping object that is backed by the system paging file instead of a file in the file system.

I want to have multiple instances of a process access the same file in the local file system. They all CreateFile with OPEN_ALWAYS on the same file name and pass that handle to CreateFileMapping. These are not child processes sharing the same file handle. These are multiple instances opening the same local file by name.

In this situation does it matter if the mapping object name is used or not? Is it needed? Does it automatically share the same file buffer cache because the file handle points to the same file, or is the name necessary to have cache consistency?

Comment: Going from memory, you need to use the same name for the file mapping object if you want consistency across different machines accessing the same file over the network.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Good point, thank you. I failed to specify that this is for a file on the local file system.

Comment: It's right there in the docs.  "With one important exception, file views derived from any file mapping object that is backed by the same file are coherent or identical at a specific time. [...] The exception is related to remote files."  So the mapping object name doesn't matter.

Comment: @arx, the statement "at a specific time" combined with some testing is what has left me wondering. If multiple processes create separate file mapping objects backed by the same file, do they still share the file mapping buffer as if they had used a named file mapping object, or do they have separate buffers that are synced occasionally and thus 'coherent or identical at a specific (sync) time'? If sharing a file mapping object by name does not give any better cache consistency in this case, please post your response as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @jla: For local files, the mappings are neither more nor less consistent than memory itself.  That is, you may need a memory barrier to ensure that writes hit the bus in a certain order, otherwise they can be reordered within the CPU pipeline.  Treat those pointers the same way as any other pointer to memory shared with other threads.